# Rails integration test fails on redirect_to show after create succeeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

An integration test fails in my Rails 4.2.4 app with this error:

> test_create_subject_pathway#SubjectPathwaysTest (1446991554.60s)
>           expecting <"subjects/show"> but rendering with <[]>
>           test/integration/subject_pathways_test.rb:33:in `block in '

The assertion concerning the flash content demonstrates within the test that the new subject was successfully saved. Use of pry showed that more directly. I cannot see why the redirection to 'subjects/show' is failing in the test. When I follow this path within a browser the redirection succeeds.

A Google search turned up similar problems but none seemed to be directly applicable. My hope is that other eyes will spot my error.

The app is based on the Michael Hartl tutorial and passes all tests related to that tutorial's completed application. The app will track research subjects so a Subject model has been added.

```
class CreateSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :subjects do |t|
      t.string  :first
      t.string  :middle
      t.string  :last
      t.date    :dob
      t.integer :age
      t.string  :gender

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The controller:

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_subject, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @subjects = Subject.order(last: :asc, 
                              first: :asc, 
                              middle: :asc).page params[:page]
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @subject = Subject.new
  end

  def create
    @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)
    if @subject.save
      flash[:success] = "Subject was saved."
      redirect_to @subject
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
  ...
private
  def set_subject
    @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  end

  def subject_params
    params.require(:subject).permit(:first, 
      :middle, :last, :dob, :age, :gender)
  end
end
```

The routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  match '/home',    to: 'static_pages#home',    via: 'get'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#create',      via: 'post'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  resources :subjects do
  end
end
```

And finally the integration tests with the failing assertion:

```
require 'test_helper'
class SubjectPathwaysTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @user = User.new( name:  'user', 
                      email: 'user@abc.com', 
                      password:              'password', 
                      password_confirmation: 'password',
                      admin: false,
                      activated: true,
                      activated_at: Time.zone.now )
    @user.save!
  end

  test 'create subject pathway' do
    sign_in_as @user
    follow_redirect!
    # follow subject link
    get subjects_path
    assert_template 'subjects/index'
    # insert new subject
    assert_select "a[href=?]", new_subject_path
    get new_subject_path
    assert_template 'subjects/new'
    post subjects_path, subject: { first:  'Joe',
                                   middle: 'T',
                                   last:   'Garcia',
                                   dob:     '',
                                   age:     55,
                                   gender:  'M' }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_equal 'Subject was saved.', flash[:success]
    assert_template 'subjects/show'  # <-- This fails!!
  end
end
```

test_helper provides this method:

```
  # Signs in a test user.
  def sign_in_as(user, options={})
    password = options[:password] || 'password'
    if integration_test?
      post signin_path, session: { email:    user.email,
                                   password: password }
    else
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution was staring me in the face. A follow_redirect! is required before the assert_template 'subjects/show'. See the code  snippet below. Without the follow_redirect! a template is not actually 'rendered'.

```
test 'create subject pathway' do
  ...
  post subjects_path, subject: { first:  'Joe',
                                 middle: 'T',
                                 last:   'Garcia',
                                 dob:     '',
                                 age:     55,
                                 gender:  'M' }
  assert_not flash.empty?
  assert_equal 'Subject was saved.', flash[:success]
  follow_redirect!                 # <-- Added this line
  assert_template 'subjects/show'  # <-- No longer fails
```

end